# Switching between breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to switch between breakpoints in normal mode not in run mode in c# using keyboard shortcut

See, if I keep a break point on top and bottom of the coded page, its difficult to scroll up and down as the code is very lengthy, so I need to know the shortcut to switch over breakpoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> it open a break point window and you can navigate

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a Breakpoint-Window which shows all of your Breakpoints. So you can easily jump between them. Searching Breakpoints is also available there.

VS Menu: `Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can open `Breakpoints` window (Ctrl+D, B) and all your breakpoints will be displayed there. Double-click will navigate to line. You can also assign labels to breakpoints to find them easier:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use use bookmarks to navigate code quickly. The standard shortcuts for me is
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to create one and remove,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to go to Next and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> to go to Previous